# ASP.NET Default page for particular user

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Im using .NET Membership for user authentication.

I whould like to set a default page for a particular user after login. Is it possibile via web.config or something ?

Example all users goes to Default.aspx after login

SuperUser goes to Admin.aspx after login.

Thank you

Comment: Are you using web forms or mvc?

Comment: We are using WEB FORMS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the LoggedIn Method of login control:

```
protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Login1.UserName == "YourUserName")
        Login1.DestinationPageUrl = "YourDestinationPageUrl";
}
```

Comment: thank you  but we are not using Login Control but the default <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" /> created by the template